# Разница в ссылках

Tags: java

Есть ли разница между:

```
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        persons.add(new Person(db.getName(i), db.getAge(i)));
    }
```

и

```
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Person person = new Person (db.getName(i), db.getAge(i));
        persons.add(person);
    }
```

Интересует с точки зрения быстродействия и расхода памяти.

Comment: Вы пытались самостоятельно ответить на этот вопрос и выработать аргументацию для этого?

Comment: разницы нет, компилятор второй случай приведет к первому и будет одно и тоже

Comment: @etki Я думаю первый вариант лучше, т.к. там вроде как слабая ссылка.

Comment: Можно же самому проверить, измерив время выполнения кода в обоих случаях.

Comment: @Рома, во втором случае у вас ссылка существует только до следующей итерации, после чего она указывает на следующий элемент. С точки зрения памяти, первый вариант чуть меньше расходует, но это ничтожно мало в современных объемах, размер ссылки в памяти крутится где то около 4-8 байт в реализации java от Sun и Oracle. Но второй вариант более читаем, а в случаях когда в конструкторе нет нужных параметров, а нам необходимо их задать или вызвать метод до добавления в коллекцию первый вариант никак не подойдет. Еще есть Stream API но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: @Tr1nks если он вообще расходует. Для передачи нового объекта в метод нужно сначала сохранить где-то ссылку на него, очевидно, все в том же стэке.

Comment: @etki Ну чисто с точки зрения памяти как таковой, а не ее выделения ссылка занимает этот объем, другое дело что пока она есть пока заняты эти 8 байт (для х64 системы) и как только ее нет то место свободно, а вот в какой памяти она этот объем занимает это уже другой вопрос. С точки зрения производительности это ничто, особенно в современных объемах памяти, да и не asm это, нет тут смысла байты считать когда рядом конструкции встречаются типа (String)+(String) в циклах